# Is is wrong for the first sentence ? sounds strange to me

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

Parents need to relentlessly supervise their children as they are more susceptible to creating more problems and endangering themselves.(A sentence extracted from an essay)
or
Parents need to relentlessly supervise their children as they are more susceptible to create more problems and endangering themselves.

Comment: Both sentences are far too wordy.

Comment: 'Relentlessly' is wrong here. It should be 'diligently' or 'vigilantly'.'Susceptible to creating' is wrong, also; it is a non-sequitur.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples seem to overuse 'more', particularly given that they're opening sentences where no precedent has been set for susceptibility to- or a quantity of problems. In addition 'Relentlessly' seems to carry some subjective weight.

Perhaps 'thoroughly' would be a suitable alternative for 'relentlessly' and would carry fewer negative connotations?

I'd suggest '*Children are susceptible to create problems and endangering themselves and so should be thoroughly supervised by parents*'.